# NestJs unit test crashes due to decorators

Tags: jestjs, nestjs

I have a NestJS Jest-based unit test that keep crashing due to some parameter-scoped decorators somewhere in the import tree, for example, in this case, I had some methods whose first parameter had a `@Args` decorator from Graphql:

```
async getUserById(@((0, _graphql.Args)('id'))
                  ^
SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

If I try to enable `babel-plugin-parameter-decorator` in babel.config, it starts breaking other things, for example, it stops recognizing @Prop types correctly on my schemas, or throws a message-less "TypeError" when I try to reference my schema's `.name` property like here:

```
// my.service.ts:
@Injectable
export class MyService {
    private logger = new Logger(MyService.name)
    constructor(
        @InjectModel(MyModel.name) private myModel: Model<MyModel>,
    ) {
    }
}
```

Any idea how I should get jest to work?

Comment: ts-jest should support this by default. I've never ran into this problem before

Answer (score 0):

as [jay-mcdoniel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9576186/jay-mcdoniel) hinted, that was the problem. I was not using ts-jest. Had to add to package.json's `jest` section:

```
        "transform": {
            "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
        },
```